# SQLのIN句に使う複数の値を名前付きパラメータで指定したい

Tags: java, spring

フレームワークはSpringを使用しています。
`NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`クラスなどを使って下記のプレースホルダ(:idの部分)に対して複数の値を並べてSQLを実行させることは可能でしょうか。テーブルからとってきた複数のuserIdを下記のプレースホルダに並べてSQLを実行させるようにしたいと考えていますが、どう実装すれば分からず悩んでいます。
■プレースホルダ含むSQL文

```
// SQLの定義
String sql = "select name from sampletbl where id in(:id)";
```

Answer (score 3):

in句に渡すパラメータをSetなどのコレクションにすると、その要素数分プレースホルダが作られて値がせっとされます。

```
    Set<Integer> ids = new HashSet<>();
    ids.add(1);
    ids.add(2);
    ids.add(3);

    MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    parameters.addValue("ids", ids);
    List<String> result = this.namedJdbcTemplate.query("select name from sampletbl where id in (:ids)", parameters, (resultSet, i) -> resultSet.getString("name"));
    System.out.println(result);
```

実行時には、以下のようなSQLとなります。

```
select name from sampletbl where id in (?, ?, ?)
```